# PayPal in-app purchase without implementing PayPal

Tags: ios, paypal

I'm building an app where user can buy a virtual good from another user in the app. When tapping the BUY button the user is redirected to Safari in order to login to PayPal, make a transaction and after everything is ok the server is notified about that and notifies back the app that the transaction is complete. I'm still not sure if Apple will reject my app, but I think it will. Can someone clarify this to me? I know I'm not allowed to send virtual goods except using in-app purchases, but I want to send money from one user to another in the app. Is there other way to achieve this? 
P.S. PayPal is implemented on server and when I tap buy button it returns some specific url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with an answer. After tapping the Buy button, I will just present some waiting screen and provide the server with the user's PayPal account (username and password, which will be entered in settings in the app). And the rest of the work will be done on server side. I am quite sure that this approach will not be rejected by Apple.